# Как получить доступ к свойству объекта в массиве, находящемся в объекте, который в свою очередь находится в одном общем массиве?

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет! Не могу понять, как получить данные из одного общего массива, в котором хранятся объекты, в которых есть другой массив, содержащий два объекта :) Эта вложенность она просто убивает.
Получаю только значения свойства key, т.е. только букву с которой начинается имя автора.
Необходимо получить и вставить через шаблонные строки следующие значения: authors => items => author и authors => items => books.length. Чтобы в разметке выводились имя автора и количество его книг.

```html
<h1>Библиотека современных авторов</h1>
    <section class="author-filter">
      <h2>Поиск авторов по алфавиту</h2>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul class="site-nav">
          <!--ссылки из букв-->
          <li class="site-nav-item">
            <a class="site-nav-link" href="#а">А</a>
          </li>
          <li class="site-nav-item">
            <a class="site-nav-link">Б</a>
          </li>
          <li class="site-nav-item">
            <a class="site-nav-link" href="#в">В</a>
          </li>
          <li class="site-nav-item">
            <a class="site-nav-link">Г</a>
          </li>
          <li class="site-nav-item">
            <a class="site-nav-link" href="#Д">Д</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
    <section class="authors">
      <section class="authors-section">
        <h2 id="А">А</h2>
        <ul class="author-list">
          <li class="author-item">
            <a class="author-link" data-value="Абрагимов Руслан" href="#">
              <h3>Абрагимов Руслан</h3>
              <p>12 книг</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="author-item">
            <a class="author-link" data-value="Абрамова Валентина" href="#">
              <h3>Абрамова Валентина</h3>
              <p>6 книг</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="author-item">
            <a class="author-link" data-value="Абрамс Рей" href="#">
              <h3>Абрамс Рей</h3>
              <p>5 книг</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="author-item">
            <a class="author-link" data-value="Азарова Александра" href="#">
              <h3>Азарова Александра</h3>
              <p>8 книг</p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
```

```js
const authors = [
  {
    key: 'А',
    items: [
      {
        author: 'Адамс Гай',
        books: [
          {
            genre: 'Детские книги',
            title: 'Очень добрая история',
            year: '2020',
            img: 'book-cover-345.jpg',
            price: '560 ₽',
            summary: 'Мудрая и добрая сказка, в которой просто и проникновенно говорится о самом важном: о дружбе, любви, о том, как важно помогать друг другу. Книга знакомит читателя с историей девочки Анны, которая приехала в маленький угрюмый городок. Своими поступками она запустила цепочку добрый дел и подружила всех жителей города, которые уже и забыли, как радоваться жизни.',
          },
          {
            genre: 'Детские книги',
            title: 'Чудище по имени Лень',
            year: '2019',
            img: 'book-cover-348.jpg',
            price: '480 ₽',
            summary: 'Сказка о необычном чудовище, которое иногда приходит ко всем. Герои сказки узнают, что это самая обычная лень, которая живёт в каждом из нас. На борьбу с ленью они приглашают звёздного мага, который способен победить чудовище.',
          },
          {
            genre: 'Детские книги',
            title: 'Загадка таинственного озера',
            year: '2018',
            img: 'book-cover-347.jpg',
            price: '630 ₽',
            summary: 'Тайну этого озера не могут разгадать уже много лет. Но оно совсем не страшное, а наоборот, с волшебной и чистой водой, способной дать силу и уставшему путнику и раненому зверю.',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        author: 'Агутин Леонид',
        books: [
          {
            genre: 'Детские книги',
            title: 'Лесной оркестр',
            year: '2019',
            img: 'book-cover-346.jpg',
            price: '1100 ₽',
            summary: 'Все жители леса объединились, чтобы устроить Мишке сюрприз на День Рождения. Что же было подарком на День Рождения и как отметили этот день лесные жители.',
          },
          {
            genre: 'Художественная литература',
            title: 'Хранитель снов',
            year: '2016',
            img: 'book-cover-353.jpg',
            price: '460 ₽',
            summary: 'Происходит ужасное – у всех людей в мире пропали добрые сны и мечты. На помощь приходит хранитель снов. Но ему не обойтись без помощи своих юных друзей.',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: 'Б',
    items: [
      {
        author: 'Белицкая Светлана',
        books: [
          {
            genre: 'Хобби и досуг',
            title: 'Беззаботная лама',
            year: '2017',
            img: 'book-cover-350.jpg',
            price: '460 ₽',
            summary: 'Легкая и юмористическая история о ламе, которую ничего никогда не заботит. У нее все всегда хорошо. Ничто на свете не может огорчить беззаботную ламу.',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: 'В',
    items: [
      {
        author: 'Вагнер Марк',
        books: [
          {
            genre: 'Художественная литература',
            title: 'Единорожка',
            year: '2015',
            img: 'book-cover-354.jpg',
            price: '760 ₽',
            summary: 'Приключения забавного и неуклюжего единорожки Лилу, который отправился на поиски друзей. Добрая и поучительная история, полная забавных приключений.',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: 'Г',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Д',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Е',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Ё',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Ж',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'И',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Й',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'К',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Л',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'М',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Н',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'О',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'П',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Р',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'С',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Т',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'У',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Ф',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Х',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Ц',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Ч',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Ш',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Щ',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Ы',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Э',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Ю',
    items: [],
  },
  {
    key: 'Я',
    items: [],
  },
];
```

```js
const authorsSection = document.querySelector('.authors-section');
authorsSection.innerHTML = '';

const listAuthors = authors.map((author) => `
    <h2 id=${author.key}>${author.key}</h2>
    <ul class="author-list">
      <li class="author-item">
        <a class="author-link" data-value="" href="#">
          <h3>${author.items}</h3>
          <p>${author.items}книг</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
`).join(''); 

authorsSection.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', listAuthors);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Явно же для массива в массиве одного `map` недостаточно.

```js
const authors = [];
const listAuthors = authors.map(author => `
    <h2 id=${author.key}>${author.key}</h2>
    <ul class="author-list">` + 
    author.items.map(i => `
      <li class="author-item">
        <a class="author-link" data-value="" href="#">
          <h3>${i.author}</h3>
          <p>${i.books.length} книг(а/и)</p>
        </a>
      </li>`).join('')
    + `</ul>
`).join('');
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь все работает! Я понимал, что одного map  будет недостаточно и пытался сделать внутри основного map - другой, но никак не получалось. Теперь все отлично сработало и я понял свою ошибку.

Comment: @SpartacusAW Очень хорошо. Успехов.

Comment: спасибо и взаимно.